# HTML drop down disabled strong option

Tags: html

I am trying to set categories within a HTML drop down menu. More specifically, I need to group cities based on the location in a country.

In line 2 I have the value disabled. Instead of it being a lighter color in the drop down menu, where or what do I need to do, to make this a more bold font? Or is the disabled function the incorrect way to handle this properly?

```html
<select name="startinglocation" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select a city...</option>
    <option disabled value="austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="innsbruck">Innsbruck</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with `optgroup` tags.  Here's an example:

```html
<select name="startinglocation" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select a city...</option>
    <optgroup label="Austria">
        <option value="innsbruck">Innsbruck</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

In addition to making the group name bold, this will also indent the values inside each group.

---

Just for completeness, even though it is the **wrong** way to do what you want, since it does have other legitimate uses, here's how to style the disabled `option` elements of a `select` box using CSS:

```
option[disabled] {
    /* Styles here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for. Been almost a decade since I have last messed with any coding of any sort. Will the the optgroup function have any ill effects when trying to save to a database?

Comment: It will have no ill effects.